# I want to change a json format after fetching using javascript

Tags: javascript, json

1. I have a json like below..after fetching this json i stored in one variable called data.I need to change this data variable as bellow

   ```
     {
   "recipes": [
   {
   "cuisine": "chinese",
   "description": "hjkhdkd",
   "id": 3,
   "min_time": "30-60min",
   "name": "Noodles",
   "nutrition": "",
   "qty": "",
   "quantity_unit_id": "2",
   "rate": "",
   "recipe_type": "vegetarian",
   "serve": [
   "4"
   ],
   "tip": "",
   "image_url": {
   "medium": "/system/recipes/images/000/000/003/medium/dfdfs.jpeg?1501851554"
   }
   }
   ]
   }
   ```
2. how i can change above json data like bellow using javascript

   ```
   [
   {
   "cuisine": "chinese",
   "description": "hjkhdkd",
   "id": 3,
   "min_time": "30-60min",
   "name": "Noodles",
   "nutrition": "",
   "qty": "",
   "quantity_unit_id": "2",
   "rate": "",
   "recipe_type": "vegetarian",
   "serve": [
   "4"
   ],
   "tip": "",
   "image_url": {
   "medium": "/system/recipes/images/000/000/003/medium/dfdfs.jpeg?1501851554"
   }
   }
   ]
   ```

Comment: `data = data.recipes`

Answer (score 1):

```
var data = '{ "recipes": [ { "cuisine": "chinese", "description": "hjkhdkd", "id": 3, "min_time": "30-60min", "name": "Noodles", "nutrition": "", "qty": "", "quantity_unit_id": "2", "rate": "", "recipe_type": "vegetarian", "serve": [ "4" ], "tip": "", "image_url": { "medium": "/system/recipes/images/000/000/003/medium/dfdfs.jpeg?1501851554" } } ] }';
var jsonifieddata = JSON.parse(data);
var newdata = jsonifieddata.recipes;
JSON.stringify(newdata);
```

Run this in your console.

A suggestion: share some effort you have made when you ask on stackoverflow again.